# Compiling problem with simple exercise in C to create all possible combinations of two two-digit numbers

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, output

**Given task:**
Create a function that displays all different combination of two digits between 00
and 99, listed by ascending order. Allowed functions - write

**My Problem:**
After compiling with gcc, the a.out file shows no output/is empty.

**My solution:**

```
#include <unistd.h>

void ft_putchar(char c)
{
    write(1, &c, 1);
}

void add_space(void)
{
    ft_putchar(' ');
}


void add_comma_space(void)
{
    ft_putchar(',');
    ft_putchar(' ');
}

void ft_print_comb2(void)
{
    char i, j, k, l;
    for(i = '0'; i <= '9'; i++)
    {
        for(j = i + '1'; j <= '9'; j++)
        {
            ft_putchar(i);
            ft_putchar(j);
            add_space();    
        }
        for(k = '0'; k <= '9'; k++)
        {
            for(l = k + '1'; l <= '9'; l++)
            {
                ft_putchar(k);
                ft_putchar(l);
                if(k != '8' && l != '9')
                    add_comma_space();
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    ft_print_comb2();
    return (0);
}
```

**What I tried:**
I asked ChatGPT and Bing Chat. The code seems fine and should be able to complete the task AFAIK.
I also compiled the code in an online compiler to make sure its not a problem with my compiler. The result was the same (no output/empty a.out file).

EDIT:
To elaborate, I'm compiling with `gcc "filename"` and then try to access a.out with `./a.out`.
I had no problems with other exercises doing it this way prior to this one.
Here is my console:

```
PC@PC MINGW64 /filepath
$ gcc ft_print_comb2.c

PC@PC MINGW64 /filepath
$ ./a.out

PC@PC MINGW64 /filepath
$
```

Comment: "I asked ChatGPT" Don't get used to that habbit. Language models based on statistics aren't good at programming. You can also ask your neighbor's dog for help.

Comment: If the `a.out` file is empty, you should get some compiler errors. How do you compile and run your code?

Comment: Please add the exact command lines and all output to the question, not in comments. "No output" would require that you have an `a.out` file that you can run. That is different from `a.out` empty which means compilation failed and you cannot run your program.

Comment: @Gerhardh At least the neighbour's dog would bark in protest if one shows up at their house with the code, so I guess the dog is a better programmer than ChatGPT :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a book and start to study from that.

The code you've presented won't output anything:

```
for(j = i + '1'; j < '9'; ...
```

Starting with i holding 48 (the ASCII value of '0') then adding 49 (the ASCII for '1') results in 97... That is NOT less than the ASCII value for '9', so the inner loop never runs...

And this happens two times in your code.

Crack open a book and learn to write your own code.

Comment: That's what I'm currently trying to do with these exercises. Thanks for explaining what I'm doing wrong though, I will try to better myself.

Comment: @peacedummy Just re-reading my words that come across as harsh. Sorry about that. Hint. What's the difference between this problem ("a pair of double digits") and counting from 0000 to 9999? Think about how an odometer works...

Comment: No worries, we all need our morning coffee. You still answered what the problem was. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your first loop starts with `i = '0'`, `'0'` is `48` in the ascii table. Your second loop starts at `j = i + '1'` and ends at `j <= '9'`. Remember `i` is `48`, `48+49` is `97`, which is a lot bigger than `'9'`, which is `57`, so your inner loop does not run at all.

The next 2 loops have the same problem.